# Calculate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Calculate

$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}$  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$(-1)^{n}$$ \frac {1}{2^n}$

my attempt : 
\begin{align}\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac {1}{2^n}&=\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}(-1)^n(  1+ 1/2 + 1/2^2 +\dots+ 1/2^n)\\
&=\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}(-1)^n\frac { ( 1-(1/2)^n)}{ 1-1/2}\\
&=\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty}(-1)^n2
\end{align}

Is  it correct ??? as  Im not  able to proceed Further  Pliz help me....

Comment: Your first equality is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(- \frac{1}{2})^n$.

Geometric series !

Comment: can u  elaborate  the answer more ,,,@Fred

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}q^n=(1-q)^{-1}$  for $|q|<1$.